# if loop does not end after return

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Members,

i'm breaking my head for many hours, why my code isn't working.

I'm getting data from CSV file, and i'm trying to change one value, when two codes matches.

```
def mode(x):
for line in data_df['Bar_Code']:
    #print(line) ~ Line outputs the Barcodes in the Bar_Code Column of the CSV file.
    with open("Barcodes_to_match.txt") as barcodes:
        for barcode in barcodes:
            #print(barcode) ~ Outputs the Barcode that it need to be matched.
            if barcode == line:
                x = x.replace("True", "False")
                return x

data_df['Published'] = data_df['Published'].apply(lambda x: mode(x))

data_df.to_csv(('Products.csv'), encoding='UTF-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='"', index=None, sep=str(","))
```

The Product.csv file:

```
Bar_Code, Product, Published
BLA00BLA00, Product1, True
BLU00BLU00, Product2, False
BLI00BLI00, Product3, True
BLE00BLE00, Product4, False
```

Barcodes_to_match.txt:

```
BLA00BLA00
BLI00BLI00
```

So, i need to change the values for **Product** rows(BLA00BLA00 and BLI00BLI00) **Published** column to **False**

Can someone check my method to Replace the Values?

Thanks!

Edit:
When i add print command, it seems that the code is stocked at the last match in endless loop.

```
if barcode == line:
   print(barcode + " = " + line)
   x = x.replace("True", "False")
   return x

Output:
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
BLI00BLI00 = BLI00BLI00
```

Comment: "if loop does not end after `return`"?  This is a contradiction.  `return` exits the function; the loop can't run any more after that.  See any tutorial on functions.

Comment: If you need more help, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is that code supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get your code to run, to achieve what you wanted, try this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('Products.csv')
print(data_df)

with open("Barcodes_to_match.txt") as f:
    barcodes = f.read().splitlines()

data_df.loc[data_df['Bar_Code'].isin(barcodes), 'Published'] = False

print(data_df)

data_df.to_csv(('Products.csv'), encoding='UTF-8', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='"', index=None, sep=str(","))
```

Products.csv

```
"Bar_Code","Product","Published"
"BLA00BLA00","Product1","False"
"BLU00BLU00","Product2","False"
"BLI00BLI00","Product3","False"
"BLE00BLE00","Product4","False"
```